# Soma e Multiplicação com itens de um CSV

Tags: python, csv, soma

boa noite!
Sou novo em programação e estou aprendendo a programar em python.
Além disso, tenho tentado criar algo que é relativamente simples, mas estou encontrando dificuldade em executar.

Importei uma lista de itens do csv, que basicamente são: Item e PerCapita;
Fiz toda a importação e transformação para listas:

```
import csv
arquivo = open('mhpercapitacm.csv')
linha = csv.reader(arquivo)
for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.split(";")
```

Agora minha dificuldade é fazer com que os itens sejam multiplicados pela quantidade de hóspedes e se somem. Segue abaixo a lista dos itens.

> ['PÃO AUSTRALIANO', '0.0007\n']
>   ['PÃO CROISSANT', '0.106\n']
>   ['PÃO DE AZEITE  GRANDE', '0.0027\n']
>   ['PAO DE FORMA', '0.0089\n']
>   ['PAO DE FORMA INTEGRAL', '0.0057\n']
>   ['PAO DE QUEIJO', '0.014\n']
>   ['PÃO DOCE COM FRUTAS', '0.0036\n']
>   ['PÃO DOCE DE COCO', '0.0022\n']
>   ['PÃO DOCE DE CREME', '0.0036\n']
>   ['PÃO DOCE GOIABADA', '0.0024\n']
>   ['PÃO FRANCÊS 50G', '0.0084\n']
>   ['PÃO FRANCES MINI 25g', '0.0084\n']
>   ['PÃO INTEGRAL C/ AVEIA', '0.0015\n']
>   ['PÃO ITALIANO C/ CALABRESA', '0.0016\n']
>   ['PÃO LUA DE MEL', '0.0036\n']
>   ['PÃO RECIFINHO', '0.0032\n']
>   ['PÃO SEDINHA', '0.004\n']
>   ['PÃO SETE GRÃOS', '0.0031\n']
>   ['ACHOCOLATADO', '0.0257\n']
>   ['IOGURTE DE AMEIXA', '0.0081\n']
>   ['IOGURTE DE MORANGO', '0.0137\n']
>   ['LEITE DESNATADO', '0.007\n']
>   ['LEITE INTEGRAL', '0.0588\n']
>   ['SUCO DE ABACAXI', '0.0142\n']
>   ['SUCO DE ACEROLA', '0.0343\n']
>   ['SUCO DE CAJU', '0.176\n']
>   ['SUCO DE GOIABA', '0.162\n']
>   ['SUCO DE MANGA ', '0.243\n']
>   ['SUCO DE TANGERINA', '0.213\n']
>   ['SUCO DETOX', '0.0219\n']
>   ['SUCO CAJA', '0.0219\n']
>   ['ABACAXI MEDIO', '0.0501374969984703\n']
>   ['GOIABA', '0.00739496845444968\n']
>   ['MAMAO FORMOSA', '0.0683925779441316\n']
>   ['MARACUJA', '0.00643367648577763\n']
>   ['MELANCIA', '0.0646550130974509\n']
>   ['MELÃO ESPANHOL', '0.0466495073368142\n']
>   ['SALADA DE FRUTAS', '0.0229433868317184\n']
>   ['TANGERINA', '0.0064\n']
>   ['PEITO DE PERU DEFUMADO FATIADO', '0.008\n']
>   ['PRESUNTO COZIDO FATIADO', '0.00803951120728223\n']
>   ['QUEIJO COALHO FATIADO', '0\n']
>   ['QUEIJO MINAS', '0.00956485890977167\n']
>   ['QUEIJO MUSSARELA FATIADO', '0.0050199203187251\n']
>   ['QUEIJO PRATO FATIADO', '0.00999494167334197\n']
>   ['SALAME ITALIANO', '0.008\n']
>   ['BANANA COZIDA', '0.0134\n']
>   ['BATATA DOCE', '0.0219\n']
>   ['CARNE DE CHARQUE ', '0.0173\n']
>   ['CARNE DE SOL ISCA', '0.0193\n']
>   ['CUSCUZ DE MILHO', '0.0184\n']
>   ['INHAME', '0.0145\n']
>   ['LINGUIÇA FINA', '0.0201\n']
>   ['MACAXEIRA', '0.11\n']
>   ['MINI MISTO', '0\n']
>   ['OVOS MEXIDOS ', '0.0166\n']
>   ['PAPA DE AVEIA', '0.0166\n']
>   ['BOLO DE CENOURA', '0.0029\n']
>   ['BOLO DE CHOCOLATE', '0.0048\n']
>   ['BOLO DE LARANJA', '0.0035\n']
>   ['BOLO DE ROLO ', '0.0103\n']
>   ['BOLO DE TAPIOCA S/ GLUTEM', '0.0034\n']
>   ['BOLO FORMIGUEIRO', '0.0029\n']
>   ['BOLO INGLES', '0.004\n']
>   ['BOLO LARANJA DIET', '0.0026\n']
>   ['BOLO MESCLADO', '0.0039\n']
>   ['BOLO SOUZA LEÃO', '0.0105\n']<

Enfim, alguém tem alguma ideia de como me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Comment: O que você não consegue fazer, não ficou muito claro na sua pergunta

Comment: Num csv de 2 colunas e x linhas, o que queres seria basicamente multiplicar a coluna 1 pela 2 da primeira linha, e somar com a multiplicação da coluna 1 pela 2 da segunda linha e assim por diante ?

Comment: Desculpem a falta de clareza. O que eu quero fazer basicamente é:

Item do Cardápio = PerCapita * Número de Hóspede

Sendo o 'Item do Cardápio' a coluna A do arquivo, o 'PerCapita' a coluna B do arquivo e o Número de Hóspede uma variável na qual eu darei entrada aleatoriamente.

Só que preciso realizar essa conta em todas as linhas existentes e somar o valor delas no final.

Comment: Entendi o que você quer fazer, só não entendi o pq você não consegue. Qual a sua dificuldade, não consegue acessar o elemento da lista para mutiplicar, não consegue converter para `float`, não consegue somar no resultado final? Com isso pode te ajudar a sanar suas dúvidas

Comment: Era acessar o elemento mesmo, mas o código abaixo deu certo! Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, o item do cardápio é acessado por linha[1] como string. Aí você precisa converter para float caso queira multiplicar pelo número de hóspedes: float(linha[1]).

Nesse caso:

```
import csv
arquivo = open('mhpercapitacm.csv')
linha = csv.reader(arquivo)
numeroHospedes = 10;
valorTotal = 0;

for linha in arquivo:
    linha = linha.split(";")
    item = float(linha[1])
    valorCalculado = item * numeroHospedes
    print (valorCalculado)
    valorTotal += valorCalculado

print(valorTotal)
```

Comment: Foi! Muito obrigado!!